# Relationship between User and Roles Spring Security

Tags: mysql, hibernate, orm

I've created a class User (Usuario) and I need to do a relationship with the class Rules, but I'm facing a problem about relationship:

My class User (Usuario):

```
@Entity
public class Usuario implements UserDetails  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String email;
    private String senha;
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();

    //there are getters, setters and methods of UserDetails
```

Class Role:

```
@Entity
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String nome;
    //private TipoRole nome;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.nome;
    }
}
```

I've inserted the roles ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER in the entity Role, but the database is not allowing more than one user per role

By default, all users created in the system are RULE_USER, but it works only in the first time:

[first time ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjGs0.png)

Nevertheless, in the next time, the database doesn't allow to record a new user:

I've tried even using sql command:

insert into usuario_roles(Usuario_email, nome) values ('user@test.com', 'ROLE_USER');

Error message: 11:42:27 insert into usuario_roles(Usuario_email, nome) values ('user@test.com', 'ROLE_USER')    Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mvpnfinance`.`usuario_roles`, CONSTRAINT `FK_j30w68qri0gjgp8irgyf68kdd` FOREIGN KEY (`Usuario_email`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`email`))  0.125 sec

[error sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTVQP.png)

UPDATE

I've changed the relationship to @ManyToMany, if I insert directly into the database is working well. But in the application I'm facing other problem.

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'ROLE_USER' for key 'PRIMARY'

I don't know why, but when I'm saving a new Person, the system tries to insert a new ROLE_USER in the table Role.

I'found this sequence that is causing this error, in my Controller class:

```
    List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
    Role role = new Role();
    role.setNome("ROLE_USER");
    roles.add(role);
    usuario.setRoles(roles);
```

If I remove these lines, the system doesn't record the role into the ManyToMany table.

Comment: Show which values are you trying to insert, first and second time?

Comment: At the first time, if I insert for instance: insert into usuario_roles(Usuario_email, nome) values ('user@test.com', 'ROLE_USER'); works well, but if I continue inserting differents values, but with the same ROLE_USER, doesn't work, for instance: insert into usuario_roles(Usuario_email, nome) values ('user2@test.com', 'ROLE_USER');

Comment: As error says : this is due to foreign key constraint, which requires unique roles. Check your table fk constraints.

Comment: the tables and constraints are generated automatically, I strong believe that the problem is related to the classes that i've shown ...

Comment: But error is about different tables. Please post their structure.

Comment: As per my knowledge your user should have the following relation in users entity for the roles. 
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL). Below is a link to an example which I have followed. http://sunilkumarpblog.blogspot.com/2016/04/social-login-with-spring-security.html

Comment: user8271644 I changed the relationship and now I can insert directly into the table, but the system is still with problem.. I've posted the UPDATE, if you can help me, thanks